# How can I move my django project to another directory?

Tags: django, python-3.x

There have been questions asked about similar things, but over 4 years ago. I'm sure those things don't apply because I have tried them and they didn't work.

I was working in a directory where I had my virtualvenv and django project but I wanted to create a new folder and move them to that new folder:
old path: `dev/python/django/`
new path: `dev/python/django/blog`

I then activated my virtualenv and moved into the directory where the manage.py file was and, as I always have, ran `python manage.py runserver` however it shot out an error:

```
File "manage.py", line 16
  ) from exc
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I haven't changed anything in my manage.py file, in fact, I didn't change anything since the last time I ran this project. Since I moved the project and the virtualenv attached to it, it no longer runs.

I tried reinstalling django in my env, but it says it already exists.  I tried running `python3 manage.py runserver` as some other posts suggest, but that doesn't work either. Same error... What am I missing? All of the paths in my files are from the `BASE_DIR` variable and no paths are absolute.

What am I missing? How can I move my django project to another directory without it breaking?
For reference: I am running linux, so I'm not sure if I need to change my PATH or anything for it to run.

Comment: "What am I missing?" => well, posting your manage.py file, the python version of your venv and the python version you're __really__ using in this new folder might have been a good start. Also, I'm not sure virtualenvs really can be moved that way - at least they weren't last time I checked (but this was years ago since there aren'r much reason to move a venv, you just rebuild it from your requirements file).